# How can I detect which subview is touched when dealing various moving subviews?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, core-animation, calayer, uitouch

The following code produces an animation of an image of a shape from the top of the screen and it drifts downward using core animation.  When the user taps, it will log whether the user tapped the image (the shape) or if they missed the shape and therefore touched the background.  This seems to work fine.  However what about when I add in other images of shapes?  I'm looking for suggestions as to how to build onto this code to allow for more detailed information to be logged.

Let's say I want to programmatically add in a UIImage of triangle, a UIImage of a square, and a UIImage of a circle.  I want all three images to start drifting from top to bottom.  They may even overlap each other as they transition.  I want to be able to log "You touched the square!" or whatever the appropriate shape I've touched. I want to be able to do so even if the square is positioned in between the triangle and the circle but part of the square is showing so I can tap it. (This example shows I'm not just wanting to interact with the top-most layer)

How do I tweak this code to programmatically add in different UIImages (various shape images perhaps) and be able to log which shape I'm touching?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
 [super viewDidLoad];

 CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake([[self view] bounds].size.width, 
                             [[self view] bounds].size.height);
 CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation 
                                    animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
 animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:[[_imageView layer] position]];
 animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:endPoint];
 animation.duration = 30.0f;
 [[_imageView layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];

 }



 - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
 UITouch *t = [touches anyObject];
 CGPoint thePoint = [t locationInView:self.view];

   thePoint = [[_imageView layer] convertPoint:thePoint toLayer:[[self view] layer]];

      if([[_imageView layer].presentationLayer hitTest:thePoint])
         {
             NSLog(@"You touched a Shape!");
             // for now I'm just logging this information.  Eventually I want to have the shape follow my figure as I move it to a new location.  I want everything else to continue animating but I when I touch a particular shape I want to have complete control on repositioning that specific shape.  That's just some insight beyond the scope of this question.  However feel free to comment about this if you have suggestions.  

         }
         else{
             NSLog(@"backgound touched");
         }

   }
```

---

I'm thinking the answer to this may have something to do with looping the the various subviews.  Look at how I'm thinking I might change the -touchesBegan method:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *t = [t anyObject];
    CGPoint thePoint = [t locationInView:self.view];
    for (UIView *myView in viewArray) {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(myView.frame, thePoint)) {....
```

Notice here I set up a viewArray and have put all my subviews in the viewArray.  Is this something I should be using?  Or perhaps something like the following if I was going to loop through my layers:

```
 for(CALayer *mylayer in self.view.layer.sublayers)
```

No matter how much I try looping through my views and or layers I can't seem to get this to work.  I feel like I may just be missing something obvious...

Answer (score 0):

I think that the culprit is the line where you change the coordinate system for `thePoint`. It should probably read `convertPoint:fromLayer:` as prior to the execution of that line, your point is in the coordinate system of self.view and I'm assuming that you would like it to be in that of the imaveView. Alternately, you might skip that line altogether and call `[t locationInView:_imageView]` instead.